# Error: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, proxy

I recently bought myself a proxy(not really experienced using them). I planned on using it to scrape reviews from trustpilot(little personal project) but I can't manage to set it up properly.

When I tried using bs4 without connecting proxy everything was working fine. But with proxy connection I get this error: requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.trustpilot.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001A14BED0590>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))). I also got error 407.

I tried multiple versions of proxy connection but none of them worked for me.

Here is the code I have at the moment:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

proxies = {'https': f'{LOGIN}{PASS}@http://173.234.30.235:11163'}

url='https://www.trustpilot.com/'

r = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers, proxies=proxies)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

I bought a residential proxy from astroproxy.com. Maybe there are some specific cases for this exact provider. This being said I highly doubt that.